# Slightly confused on central limit theorem

Tags: central-limit-theorem

It seems that the central limit theorem has many applications, but I just want to know an extremely simple one.

If I have $n$ i.i.d. random variables, $X_1,..., X_n$, and $S=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, does the CLT state that as n gets large, $S$ is approximately normal with $\mu=nE(X_i)$ and $\sigma^2=nVar(X_i)$?

Is that why you can approximate $F_{S}(s)$ as: $$\phi\left(\frac{s-nE(X_i)}{\sqrt{nVar(X_i)}}\right)$$Where $\phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution?

Comment: Probably if you want to properly state it in terms of a convergence you take averages (divide out by $n$), but otherwise yes.

Comment: I just want to know if the sum is normal, but I assume since the average is normal, the sum would be too as you are just dividing by n?

Comment: No.  Imagine $\{X_i\}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli 0/1 variables.  Then the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is always integer-valued and so its distribution does not approach a normal (Gaussian) distribution. This is why the shifting and scaling is important: $$ G_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-E[X])$$ For intuition you should compute the mean and variance of $G_n$ for each $n$.